# How to add years to date in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to add 2 years to date in SQL.

```
select left(cast(D as datetime) ,11)  from table
```

In the above query how can i add 2 years.

Output is,

```
Jan  1 2012
Jan  2 2012
Jan  3 2012
Jan  4 2012
```

but i want output as,

```
Jan  1 2014
Jan  2 2014
Jan  3 2014
Jan  4 2014
```

Thank you

Answer (score 10):

`DateAdd()` is the function you want http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx

```
SELECT DateAdd(yy, 2, Cast(d As datetime))
```

Comment: @MaxWilliams the question is tagged `sql-server`

Comment: Whoops, so it is.  My bad.

Answer (score 5):

```
select dateadd(yy,2,getdate())
```

Answer (score 0):

finally i got, Query is                                                                  SELECT left(DateAdd(yy, 2, Cast(d As datetime)),11) from table

Answer (score 0):

You **can** use convert instead of the left:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(year, 2, CAST(d AS DATETIME)), 107) FROM table
```